# Network monitor 3.4 issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-monitoring

I am getting the following error message when I try to run network monitor on a windows 2003 DNS server I am trying to decommission.

```
C:\>Nmcap.exe /network * /capture KerberosV5 || TCP.port==389 || UDP.port==389 file c:\temp\capture.chn:200mb
'Nmcap.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'TCP.port' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'UDP.port' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just throw pipe characters (|) onto the command line without escaping them or surrounding them with quotes (").  Pipe characters have special meaning to the command interpreter.  Furthermore, make sure that Nmcap.exe is either in your current working directory (e.g. C:\) or in your path environment variable.  The binary is most likely in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\` on your computer.

Something like this:

```
C:\>Nmcap.exe /network * /capture "KerberosV5 || TCP.port==389 || UDP.port==389" /file c:\temp\capture.chn
```

Read the help for Nmcap.exe: `Nmcap.exe /?`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I moved the nmcap file to c:\ and your command worked fine.

Comment: Ok this is the command I'm using :Nmcap.exe /network * /capture DNS || TCP.port==53 || UDP.port==53 file c:\te
mp\capture.chn:300mb seems to be tracking ok. Will let it run.